# PHP - trying to send an email but server don't let it

Tags: php, email, hosting

I am making a contact form in php using mail function, but the hosting is saying that I have to put into parameter 'from' email only with domain name which is the same like in the hosting. But I need to put in the 'from' email from form. Is there any way how to avoid this? I don't want to use external scripts. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Change mail server provider?

Answer (score 0):

you cant send emails with email adresses
that arent from your server because of security reasons otherwise you could send an email from zuckerberg@facebook.com or something similar.

use the answer to param to add the contact form email and put something that is from your server into the from

Comment: Okay, I had one syntax error, but now is everything working, thanks for help. :)